# How to make keras ImageGenerator load 16-bit images properly?

Tags: keras, python-imaging-library, generator, conv-neural-network, 16-bit

I've searched for similar questions but found no solution to what i am trying to do.
I have 16-bit grayscale images, and i am trying to fit them in keras ImageDataGenerator. When using functions like: flow_from_dataframe, it yields images all with the same pixel value (incorrect).

I tried using the keras preprocess_input, rescale to [0,1], to [-1,1] with a custom preprocessing function, but none of this worked. I also set the color_mode='grayscale' in ImageDataGenerator.

I further tested converting to 8-bit, and it worked. I triplicated the number of channels, and it was not the issue, since it still worked with 8-bit. I've read that keras in this case uses PIL library to read images, and since it doesn't treat 16-bit correctly, it returns that error. I saw that we could set a different library for loading images, but i don't know how to do that.

Doas anyone know an alternative for using 16-bit images? In the last case, i would try a custom generator, but i would really like to profit from already built and tested functions for this purpose.

I aim to use those images to fine-tune a pre-trained network, so i would like to standardize the type of input i use.

Thanks.

Comment: What format are the images stored in?

Comment: .tiff. 
I've also tested with .png images, and it gives the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to write your own [ImageDataGenerator](http://tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator) and overwrite some methods to load your data as you expect it.

There are [some great blog articles](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) that explain everything you need.

You then have to make sure that the overwritten `__data_generation` method loads your `.tiff` images correctly into numpy arrays or you convert them beforehand and just load them.

It is also quite straightforward to test your generator *(do it!)* and check if it produces the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in keras_preprocessing versions <= 1.1.0. Use the package directly from the source code on github to fix it. Type the following command to update your package:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing.git --upgrade --no-deps
```

And, with color_mode='grayscale', your ImageDataGenerator will load 16-bit grayscale images correctly.

This bug was fixed by Rodrigo Agundez (see [his post](https://medium.com/@rragundez/medical-images-now-supported-by-keras-imagedatagenerator-e67d1c2a1103) and the [pull request](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/pull/242) for more details) and should be published in a next release. The problem comes from keras_preprocessing when loading an image:

```
# PIL library
img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))

# This was the bug: converting with L mode will truncate all images to 8-bit.
# All values > 255 will be set to 255
if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    img = img.convert('L')

# This is the fix
if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    # if image is not already an 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit grayscale image
    # convert it to an 8-bit grayscale image.
    if img.mode not in ('L', 'I;16', 'I'):
        img = img.convert('L')
```

Be aware that if you load a 16-bit grayscale image with color_mode='rgb' (let's say if you want to convert your single grayscale channel into a 3 channel image) it wont work as the 16-bit grayscale image will be converted to 8-bit.