# How to deal with images with decimal values before and after performing CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to perform CNN for regression using grayscale images with continues pixel value in float32 data types. The value ranges for predictors:

```
img1= 0 to 790.65
img2= -2.74174 to 2.4126
img3= 150.87 to 260.45
```

The value range for response image:

```
resp_img= -32.927 to 69.333
```

Is it appropriate to convert the pixel values between [0-255], and also if I convert the data type/data range to another format how should I scale back to original floating-point values?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do. pixel values are normally in the range 0 to 255. Typically the pixel values are rescale between 0 and 1  using img=img/255 this produce floats. To convert back to range 0 to 255 as floats just do img=img * 255 or if you want an integer value img=int(img*255)

Comment: @ Gerry P, similar to this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105563/how-to-make-keras-imagegenerator-load-16-bit-images-properly], when I use ImageDataGenerator, this returns error `io.BytesIO object` in reading rgb and grayscale images with float32 data type